# oracle_fdw connect error: OCIAttrSet failed to set driver name in session handle

Tags: postgresql, oracle, oracle-call-interface, oracle-fdw

I encountered the error when I used below the script on Postgres 13.9 (oracle_fdw 2.4) on Windows 10 64-bit.

```
CREATE SERVER yf FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw OPTIONS (dbserver 'yf');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER yf OPTIONS (user 'yonker', password 'his');
GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER yf TO postgres;

SELECT oracle_diag('yf');

[HV00N]: ERROR: error connecting to Oracle: OCIAttrSet failed to set driver name in session handle
detail：ORA-24315: illegal attribute type
```

I can connect to oracle server with tnsname 'yf' using sqlplus.

- oracle client 10.2.0.4
- oracle server 11.2.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw#5-installation-requirements) states the requirements:

> Oracle client version 11.2 or better is required.

The error is thrown when oracle_fdw tries to set `OCI_ATTR_DRIVER_NAME` on the session handle, which was not available before Oracle 11.  It is no problem to use an older Oracle server version, as long as you are using a less outdated client version.

Comment: This issue bothered me for a few days, thank you for helping me solve the problem，thanks very much